# Add blur effect in a container using Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, blur

I am new in Flutter and I am trying to blur a background. I used the below function:

```
Widget loginContainer() {
    return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white70,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
        child: BackdropFilter(
            filter: ImageFilter.blur(
              sigmaX: 5.0,
              sigmaY: 5.0,
            ),
            child: getLoginContainer()));
  }

  Widget getLoginContainer() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        space(20),
        emailTextField(),
        space(10),
        passwordTextField(),
        space(10),
        forgotPassword(),
        space(20),
        loginButton(),
        space(10),
        signUpTextLine(),
        space(30),
        copyrightTextLine(),
        space(10),
      ],
    );
  }
```

But the bluring is happening on the entire screen. I saw that I can using `ClipRect` but I do not now the exact size of the Container. I just want my container, the one with the BoxDecoration, to be blured. So instead of transparency, it's blured.

On the attached picture, you can see the container which have the input text and so one. I want to have this container blured and not the entire screen

[image]

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ClipRRect` instead of `ClipRect`.

```dart
child: ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
  child: BackdropFilter(
    filter: ImageFilter.blur(
      sigmaX: 5.0,
      sigmaY: 5.0,
    ),
    child: getLoginContainer(),
  ),
),
```